# Is there a name for each of the wrecked ships in Donkey Kong Country 2?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-2

In the first world of DKC2, the Ship's name is "Gangplank Galleon". However in the second and third worlds, Crocodile Cauldron and Krem Quay both have shipwrecks in them. Apparently these both belonged to K. Rool:

> "K. Rool proves he’s pirate and not a sailor with yet another wrecked ship. Be careful or you’ll get sunk in this swamp along with it!"

[Source](https://donkeykong.fandom.com/wiki/Krem_Quay#Profiles).

Do these ships have names as well?

Comment: I've been wondering this since I'm a child.